# Grouping some lines into one

Tags: linux, lines, hosts

I have an *[hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29)* and I need to group multiple lines into one, using Linux standard commands; starting with this:

```
127.0.0.1 name1
127.0.0.1 name2
127.0.0.1 name3
...
127.0.0.1 nameN
```

I want this:

```
127.0.0.1 name1 name2 name3
127.0.0.1 name4 name5 name6
...
127.0.0.1 ... nameN
```

The ip address is always the same, and I can easily remove it to simplify the work; the file can reach 30K+ lines, so my goal is to reduce its size using as few resources as possible (I'm working on a router with OpenWRT).
Using *tail* and *head* I can get a group of lines, but then I don't know how to put them on a single line (substite *\n* with a space doesn't seem to work).

Comment: Do you always want three names per line (except for the last line)?

Comment: I think 20 (or 30) names per line should be fine to reduce the file size without having trouble; the last line will containt the remaining names (not necessarily one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
(sed 's/127.0.0.1 //' | fmt -w 25 | sed 's/^/127.0.0.1 /') < inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: I suspect that the `tr` command in your pipeline is not needed.  Won't the `fmt` merge the lines as needed anyway?

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm :)
I changed *-w 25* with *-w 100* as some names are very long; as soon as possible I will test it directly on the router.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `sed` invocation which always has up to three names on one line:

```
sed -e '1~3 N' -e 's/\n127.0.0.1//g' -e '2~3 N' -e 's/\n127.0.0.1//g' in >out
```

This works with GNU sed, I haven't tried any other sed versions:

```
voss@seehuhn [~] cat x
127.0.0.1 a
127.0.0.1 b
127.0.0.1 c
127.0.0.1 d
127.0.0.1 e
127.0.0.1 f
127.0.0.1 g
127.0.0.1 h
voss@seehuhn [~] sed -e '1~3 N' -e 's/\n127.0.0.1//g' -e '2~3 N' -e 's/\n127.0.0.1//g' x
127.0.0.1 a b c
127.0.0.1 d e f
127.0.0.1 g h
```